# ActiveRecord use joins for performance but load all associated records into memory like with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord

Unless I am mistaken: `joins` has better performance than `includes` because at the database level:

- `joins` causes an `inner join`
- `includes` causes a `subquery`

And in general, an `inner join` is faster than a `subquery`.

Example:

```
#app/models/owner.rb
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets
end 

#app/models/pet.rb
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
end
```

Using `rails console`:

```
# showing how 'includes' in rails causes an IN statement which is a subquery 
irb(main):001:0> @owners = Owner.all.includes(:pets)
Owner Load (2.7ms)  SELECT "owners".* FROM "owners"
Pet Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "pets".* FROM "pets" WHERE "pets"."owner_id" IN (1, 2, 3)
```

And now using `joins` which causes an `inner join`:

```
irb(main):001:0> @owners = Owner.all.joins(:pets)
Owner Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "owners".* FROM "owners" INNER JOIN "pets" ON "pets"."owner_id" = "owners"."id"
```

So it would seem like it would almost always be better the use `joins` over `includes` because:

- `includes` causes a `subquery` (the `IN` statement)
- `joins` causes an `inner join` which is usually faster than a subquery

However, there is one gotcha with using `joins`. [This article does a great job describing it](http://tomdallimore.com/blog/includes-vs-joins-in-rails-when-and-where/).  Basically, `includes` loads all the associated objects into memory, so that if you query for any of the attributes for those associated objects, it doesn't hit the database.  Meanwhile, `joins` DOES NOT load into memory the associated objects' attributes, so if you query for any of the attributes, it makes additional hits on the database.

So here is my question: Is it possible to do inner joins like with `joins` for performance but at the same time load all the associated objects into memory like `includes` does?
Put another way: is it possible to load all the associated objects into memory like `includes` does, but causes an inner join as opposed to a subquery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your assumption that a `JOIN` is always faster than two queries is not correct. It highly depends on the size of your database tables.

Imagine you have thousands of owners and pets in your database. Then your database had to join all together first, even if you just want to load 10 records. On the other hand one query loading 10 owners and one query to load all pets for that 10 owners would be faster than that `JOIN`.

I would argue that both methods exist to solve different problems:

- `joins` is used when you need to combine two tables to run a query on the data of both tables.
- `includes` is used to avoid N+1 queries.

Btw: The [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) has a note that `includes` has performance benefits over `joins`:

> *This will often result in a performance improvement over a simple join.*